# Create ontology using rules in protege

Tags: ontology, rules, protege

I have a three classes:

- Department: individuals "Corporate_Services" and "Finance"
- Cause: individual "vehicle_driving"
- Injury_type: individuals "minor" and "major".

I have 2 object properties:

- "has_cause": domain "Department" and range "Cause"
- "has_injury_type": domain "Cause" and range "Injury_type".

I have to create an ontology using the following rules:

1. **Corporate_Services** -> *has_cause* -> **vehicle_driving** -> *has_injury_type* -> **minor**.
2. **Finance** -> *has_cause* -> **vehicle_driving** -> *has_injury_type* -> **major**.

How to do it? I cannot use property chains because I actually have more than 3 classes.

Comment: The domain of `has_injury_type` should be not `Cause`, but something else.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Can you elaborate please